# Problem with the next-auth google provider using prisma and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, next.js, prisma, next-auth

Im having difficulties figuring out how to fix this error:

I have a next.js application that is is running on my local machine and im trying to log in with different gmail accounts but when I log in with 1 I cant log in with any other gmail account afterwards that Ive added as test-users in the google console and connected to my next.js application.

```
unique constraint failed on the constraint: users_username_key {
  message: '\n' +
    'Invalid prisma.user.create() invocation:\n' +
    '\n' +
    '\n' +
    'Unique constraint failed on the constraint: users_username_key',
  stack: 'PrismaClientKnownRequestError: \n' +
    'Invalid prisma.user.create() invocation:\n' +
    '\n' +
    '\n' +
    'Unique constraint failed on the constraint: users_username_key\n' +
    '    at si.handleRequestError (D:\prgrammeringsprojekt\next-ecommerce-project\project\node_modules@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:125:6817)\n' +
    '    at si.handleAndLogRequestError (D:\prgrammeringsprojekt\next-ecommerce-project\project\node_modules@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:125:6151)\n' +
    '    at si.request (D:\prgrammeringsprojekt\next-ecommerce-project\project\node_modules@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:125:5859)\n' +
    '    at async l (D:\prgrammeringsprojekt\next-ecommerce-project\project\node_modules@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:130:10025)',
  name: 'PrismaClientKnownRequestError'
}
```

```
user model:  model User {
  id            String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  username      String?   @unique
  password      String?
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
  Cart          Cart[]
  Review        Review[]
  Order         Order[]

  @@map("users")
}
```

I'm using prisma ORM with mongodb atlas.

I have tried to update my database with prisma after going through the schemas to see if I had made any typos but Im unavailable to understand why.

What I've done is to follow this ecommerce guide: https://youtu.be/AaiijESQH5o?t=13990

Answer (score 0):

I think the error happens because of the unique constraint on username. For example, if you have two different google accounts, with two different emails, but using the same name, the username will be the same. Make sure to have two different usernames, or as a better alternative, you can set null the username field if a user with the same username already exists, and send a response showing a page to set his username.
I don't know how your code is, but you should implement some logic like this in your signIn function

```
const existingUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
 where: {
    username: newUsername,
 },
});

if (!existingUser) {
 const newUser = await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      // your user data here
    },
 });
} else {
 // handle the case where the username already exists
}
```